# How do I know if a development board can be charged by batteries?

Tags: arduino, batteries, pcb, battery-charging

So this question might sound a bit weird since I'm pretty new to programing development boards. What I need is a board that can be powered using a battery and that also supports Bluetooth. I'm interested in the Arduino Blend Micro(https://store.arduino.cc/blend-micro), how do I know if this boards supports the usage of batteries?

It would be even greater if the board would charge its battery when connected to a power source via USB. However I have no idea what this concept is called, nor do I know how to search for a board online that supports this feature.

Comment: "how do I know the capabilities of any product" <- read the available information, and if that doesn't help, ask the supplier.

Comment: *a board that can be charged using a battery* In general **boards** cannot be charged. Perhaps what you mean is "a board which can be **powered** by a battery. In principle **all** boards can be powered by a battery". Almost all Arduino based boards can be battery powered (they do not consume much power) as long as you supply the board with the right voltage. The Arduino board does not and cannot "know" the difference between being battery powered or from an adapter. So you will not find in the description if a board can be powered from a battery as in principle all can be.

Comment: *if the board would charge its battery* **Show us** a board which has a battery which needs charging. All the Arduino boards I know do not have a battery and therefore cannot and do not need to be charged.

Comment: I would add the bettery myself and connect it to the board, so the board gets powered by the battery. And when the board gets connected to a power source via its USB port, I want to know if this power could be used for charging the battery.

Comment: Basically the same concept with a phone, you can charge it's battery by using its USB port.

Comment: Since you will be adding the battery and supporting circuitry, how does that then relate to the Arduino board ? Well, it does not. You can just power the Arduino board directly from the battery, for example the 3.6 V of a Lithium cell via a battery protection module. Then for charging you need to add a charging module (I suggest a TP4056 based module) to charge the LiIon cell from USB. That's it. You focus too much on the Arduino board which is not needed, the Arduino board doesn't need to support this, all of then do this already.

Comment: Generally for this, you want something designed around a BLE MCU alone, **without an Arduino co-processor** - this is because BLE chips and the software for them get a lot of design attention to battery lifetime, while that goal tends to be overlooked by 95% of efforts in the Arduino world.  In addition to being a poor choice, that Blend thing based on an obsolete first generation peripheral chip even costs more than a platform based around the latest generation BLE MCUs like an nRF52 or its competitors.

Answer (score 0):

Any board can be run with batteries if you match the voltage and current needed by the board.

For boards that can recharge batteries, you would look for boards with built in lithium or other battery type charger circuits. There are some arduino type boards with this built in,  but there are also modules you can buy to connect.

As a kludge, you can just use a usb battery pack. Built in battery and charging and voltage regulation.

Comment: Yes - however very few *development boards* can be used to obtain long standby (let alone) lifetime on battery, as that requires design details that typically aren't part of development board goals - the exception would be boards specifically designed to demonstrate long  battery lifetime.

Comment: @Chris sure, if you need ultra long life and not just portability.

Comment: It's not so much a question of "ultra long life" as if the application is one where the user can physically disconnect the power whenever it is not actively needed - without that, a set of batteries is likely to last no more than say 3 days, or for some projects only a few hours.